# Split string in using bash not working in debian server

Tags: bash, debian

I want to split ins_data string using " of " and get 2 numbers into 2 variables.

My code lokes like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ins_data="3,998 of 5,903"
IFS=' of ' read -ra ins_data_arr <<< ${ins_data}
total_ins=${ins_data_arr[1]//,}
missed_ins=${ins_data_arr[0]//,}

echo $total_ins
echo $missed_ins
```

This code works fine in my mac os machine.

But it is not working in Debian server.

Comment: `IFS=' of '` is *exactly* the same as `IFS=' fo'`, btw -- it defines an unordered collection of characters (well, *almost* unordered; which one is first has some important side effects), not an exact string. There are also some issues related to quoting or the lack thereof -- consider running your code through http://shellcheck.net/ and following the links in its warnings.

Comment: ...anyhow, how's this code run? If it's invoked as `sh yourscript`, there's your problem -- it's running with `sh`, not `bash`, so bash-only syntax (much of which you're using) won't be available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ins_data="3,998 of 5,903"

$ IFS=' of ' read -ra ins_data_arr <<< ${ins_data}
$ declare -p ins_data_arr
declare -a ins_data_arr='([0]="3,998" [1]="" [2]="5,903")'

$ IFS=' of ' read -ra ins_data_arr <<< "$ins_data"
$ declare -p ins_data_arr
declare -a ins_data_arr='([0]="3,998" [1]="" [2]="5,903")'
```

I found this behaviour quite confusing at first: where is that empty field coming from? I thought that any *sequence* of  IFS characters would delimit fields.

That is true *for the default value of IFS*.

This is a very subtle behaviour of IFS related to [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting):

> If `IFS` has a value other than the default, then sequences of the whitespace characters `space`, `tab`, and `newline` are ignored at the beginning and end of the word, as long as the whitespace character is in the value of `IFS` (an `IFS` whitespace character). Any character in `IFS` that is not `IFS` whitespace, along with any adjacent `IFS` whitespace characters, delimits a field. A sequence of `IFS` whitespace characters is also treated as a delimiter.

Thus: sequences of *zero or more* whitespace and a *single* non-whitespace IFS character delimit fields.

The empty array element at index 1 is the empty string between the "o" and the "f".

This test reinforces that claim:

```
$ IFS=' of ' read -ra ins_data_arr <<< "3,998 off 5,903"
$ declare -p ins_data_arr
declare -a ins_data_arr='([0]="3,998" [1]="" [2]="" [3]="5,903")'
```

Now we have an empty field between "o" and "f", and an empty field between "f" and "f".

I assume this is new behaviour as of bash version 4 -- the default bash on OSX is version 3.something. The answer to the behaviour change will be somewhere in here: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-4.4

---

Found it: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/CHANGES?h=bash-4.4#n3970

> zz. The word splitting code now treats an IFS character that is not space,
>      tab, or newline and any adjacent IFS white space as a single delimiter, as
>      SUSv3/XPG6 require.

This documents "changes between this version, bash-3.1-alpha1,
and the previous version, bash-3.0-release." -- so your "it works" version of bash must be *very* old.

---

Having said all that, my recommended fix: don't use a custom IFS, just account for the fact that you'll read 3 words:

```
$ read -r missed of total <<<"$ins_data"
$ declare -p missed of total
declare -- missed="3,998"
declare -- of="of"
declare -- total="5,903"
$ echo "${missed//,/}"
3998
$ echo "${total//,/}"
5903
```